# Missing WebParts When Page Opened In SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: 2010, web-part

Whenever I open a page in SharePoint designer the web zones are all empty. I have the page open in browser with web parts just added. Open fresh SP designer and open that web page, the web zones are now empty. I was just edited some internal CSS on the pages when all of a sudden my webparts started to disappear after a save.

- I was not saving over my page by accident.
- Refresh doesn't help.
- I tested this on four different work stations, and cleared SP Designer Cache. It messed up on every one of them.
- Happens on ALL pages under a single site, the other sites in the site collection work fine.
- When I try to add the webparts back in the browser I get the number tacked on at the end "Title(2), Title(3)" each time I try because that webpart is still being registered as being in the webzone and since they have the same name.
- I can restore old versions but the webpart zones are empty in those pages as well.

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks.

---

### update

I found that my web parts are being moved from zone 2 in PlaceHolderMain to the PlaceHolderPageTitle and into a new webzone.

This is only happening on one site within the Site collection. Same master being applied to all sites.

*Bafflement*

Any help is still appreaciated.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="__WebPartPageLibraryZone__"><ZoneTemplate>
    <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" AllowHide="True" PartImageSmall="" PartOrder="0" Title="ODRs" ManualRefresh="False" ViewGuid="{6CCD4717-B7F6-47A2-AAEF-D1BB59B14F6E}" HelpMode="Modeless" AllowEdit="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" ShowWithSampleData="False" ListId="3a670a70-e791-49dc-ad2e-cbccf1a3a5e2" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" PageSize="-1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" EnableOriginalValue="False" NoDefaultStyle="" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ExportControlledProperties="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" ViewContentTypeId="" ZoneID="g_7890C96E7E6844D1927B7015994D0531" Description="" AllowZoneChange="True" CatalogIconImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itdl.png" ID="g_6ccd4717_b7f6_47a2_aaef_d1bb59b14f6e" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." FrameState="Normal" AllowMinimize="True" Dir="Default" ViewFlag="8388621" AllowConnect="True" ListUrl="" DetailLink="/isrtopoff/home/CTC/TSAART/ODRs" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" PartImageLarge="/_layouts/images/itdl.png" TitleUrl="/isrtopoff/home/CTC/TSAART/ODRs" ListName="{3A670A70-E791-49DC-AD2E-CBCCF1A3A5E2}" FrameType="Default" DataSourceID="" IsIncludedFilter="" AllowRemove="True" HelpLink="" IsIncluded="True" IsVisible="True" AsyncRefresh="False" AutoRefresh="False" ListDisplayName="" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{6CCD4717-B7F6-47A2-AAEF-D1BB59B14F6E}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" __designer:CustomXsl="fldtypes_BambooRating.xsl;fldtypes_BambooVisualIndicator.xsl;fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><DataFields>
```

30

Comment: What happens when you access the page with contents=1 on the query string (i.e. http://sharepoint/yourwebpartpage.aspx?contents=1)? Does it show a listing of the webparts you previously added?

Comment: It does show the web parts. I found out that the webparts are being moved to the wrong webpart zone but I have no idea why. It only happens when I open the page in sharepoint designer. Tried removing that zone and adding a different one with no luck. I am going to create an entirely new page and see if it still messes up.

Comment: New pages also mess up under that site. This time it didn't even put the web part inside a <asp:content>. It was just appended to the end of the document which of course through an error. An error occurred during the processing of /isrtopoff/home/CTC/AART/SitePages/AART.aspx. Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue with one of my sites.  In order to resolve the problem I had to go as far as to take a SharePoint webpart page to start and make my structure changes needed for the page and then add the webparts from the browser.  Part of my resolution was to make the WebPartZone the same as what SharePoint used for its own pages.  Mine looks like this:  `<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:References-Zone" ID="References" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate>`   My thoughts, based on investigation, were that the ID that was being generated was causing the issue to a large degree, thus, I manually entered my ID verses having SharePoint generate it.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I just started using SharePoint Webpart Pages as templates and building onto them instead of starting with blank aspx pages. I will your suggested method though.